# How to display username of sender in chat app?

Tags: react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

I am using react-native-gifted-chat for my UI and for the backend, I am using AWSAppSync/GraphQL to store user data. I am not so sure how to go about displaying username of sender in my ChatApp and would need this feature for group chats. So far,  this is my code.

```js
import React from 'react'
import { GiftedChat } from 'react-native-gifted-chat'



class ChatScreen extends React.Component {
  state = {
    messages: [],
    username: ''


  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
      messages: [
        {
          _id: 1,
          text: 'Hello developer',
          createdAt: new Date(),
          user: {
            _id: 0,
            name: 'Default',
            avatar: 'https://placeimg.com/140/140/any',

          },


        },
      ],
    })
  }

  onSend(messages = []) {
    this.setState(previousState => ({
      messages: GiftedChat.append(previousState.messages, messages),
    }))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <GiftedChat
        messages={this.state.messages}
        renderUsernameOnMessage={true}
        onSend={messages => this.onSend(messages)}
        user={this.username}


      />
    )
  }
}

export default ChatScreen;
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this?

```
 <GiftedChat
        messages={this.state.messages}
        renderUsernameOnMessage={true}
        onSend={messages => this.onSend(messages)}
        user={this.state.username}
 />
```

Comment: Tried this and it did not display my username. I am curious to know if I have to get username from backend in order for the username to be displayed?

Comment: Updated my answer. You gave this.state for user but this.username doesn't include in your code. Also if you use this.username, although it changes you can't rerender component. So you can't see change.

Comment: but how do I show my username that I used in signing up for the chat application?

Answer (score 1):

In react native gifted chat `user` must be object containing the keys `_id`, `name` and `avatar`. `_id` will help it to separate sender and receiver. So yes, you have to set user with these properties. It not allowe only `username`.

So simple way to do this is that first fetch current user info from the server and store it into redux of asyncStorage. For example I am fetching current user from firebase as below :

```js
export const getAccountInfo = () => {
  return async dispatch => {
    const cu = auth().currentUser;
    const user = await firestore().collection('users').doc(cu.uid).get();
    dispatch({
      type: Types.INFO_FETCHED,
      data: user.data()
    });
  };
};
```

Now, In my chat screen I set user as below :

```js
<GiftedChat
  ...
  ...
  user={{
    _id: this.props.account?.user?.uid,
    name: this.props.account?.data?.fullName,
    avatar: this.props.account?.data?.avatar
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Sorry can you provide an example of what the code would be when it comes to groupchats?

Comment: @tobiappdeveloper I added example in my answer.